# Maximum Path from start node to end node given a specific number of steps

Tags: java, path, dijkstra

Currently I have an implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. Given a maze, the shortest path algorithm provides the fastest way to exit the maze from the entrance to the exit in the smallest amount of steps taken. However, I would like to find a method that, given a certain n steps, what is the maximum path possible inside the maze? (You can reach a deadend and turn back around, and it counts as additional steps)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do an inverse of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. Instead of iterating and taking the shortest option, have your program take the longest path at each location along the way to the destination node.